# SSL in JBoss 5.1.0

Tags: web-services, ssl, jboss, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am trying to enable https in jboss 5.1.0 using a trusted certificate signed by CA authority.

I carried the following steps:

1. created the keystore file
2. generated .csr file
3. generated .cer file using CA Authority
4. imported the Root, Intermediate and the generated certificate into the keystore file
5. configured the server.xml file to the keystore file.

Now I am trying to access the wsdl using https protocol in IE and I get a certificate error page 'There is a problem with this website's security certificate.' When I click on 'Continue to this website (not recommended).' nothing happens which is very strange. I would have at least expected to skip the error and see the wsdl.
MY IE browser has got both Root and intermediate certificate, also the generated certificate has got the chain linked up.

Before I tried with self signed certificate which worked fine after I installed the certificate in my browser...

Any idea how to debug or resolve the issue?

Comment: in firefox I get Error code: sec_error_inadequate_cert_type  Certificate type not approved for application.

Answer (score 0):

The application certificate was generated using the wrong template, I regenerated the certificate with the right template and is working now.